# What is the right way to use two scrollviews in a single activity?

Tags: java, android

This is my current design in my main activity.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSubestacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Subestacion"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spSubestacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtClasificacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Clasificacion"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spClasificacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollEventos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearEventos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegistros"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Actualizar Registros" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have a second scrollview inside the first one because this one is filled with multiple labels created from code. These labels can take up a lot of space, so a scrollview is suitable for proper navigation.

The first scrollview that contains everything is so that when changing the screen in landscape mode, you can continue browsing and access all the controls that are displayed.

The problem is that when changing the screen in landscape mode, only the first scrollview works, which allows you to see all the controls correctly. However, the second scrollview showing the records cannot be moved, and therefore the records are cut.

Is there a way to freeze the first scrollview when the user wants to slide the records and allow the second scrollview to be moved?
Or is it that I should create my design differently?

Note: Everything works correctly with the screen in portrait mode. All the controls are accessible at first instance and the second scrollview can be slid correctly allowing to see the records.
I've tried working with the layout_weight property but it didn't work for me or I just didn't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <!-- Other Layout or scrollView-->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Android site: [NestedScroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Comment: I just tried it but it works the same way as normal scrollviews. It didn't really fix the problem.